# how to send array of objects as response via express in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, callback

I am fetching an array of data from API via callback function.

```js
const apiFunction=(callback)=> {    
    const array=[]
    var i=0     
    while(i<3) {    
        const value={num:i}    
        array.push(value)
        i+=1 
    }
callback(array)
```

`output:array=[{num:'1'},{num:'2'},{num:'3'}]`

I am trying to send this via express my code is:

```js
const apiFunction =require('/{API function path}')
router.get('/name',(req,res)=>{
      try{
          apiFunction((data)=>{
            res.json(data)})
        }
      catch(e){
         res.status(500).send() 
    }
})
```

but upon hitting this get request i get an empty array []. please help

Comment: no i am just catching the response of my callback by a name data it can be anything

Comment: I've read wrong, my bad